# Is there a way to un-register an environment in Azure ML studio

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I am trying to deploy a model in Azure ML and kept on getting the error 'model not found' from my score.py. So I decided to start from scratch again. I had my custom environment registered, and the Azure ML API for Environment class doesn't seem to have anything like 'delete' or 'unregister'. is there a way to work around this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py&preserve-view=true#delete--) method in the [Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py) class to delete a registered model.

This can also be done via the Azure CLI as:

```
az ml model delete <model id>
```

Other commands can be found here: [az ml model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-ml/ml/model?view=azure-cli-latest)